# Regex - Match a subtring and replace it

Tags: .net, regex, replace, match

I have the following Regex that searches for a Tags h1, h2, ..., h5 and returns a match with group named **TagName** holding the Tag Name and group named **TagValue** holding the Tag Value.

```
 Public Sub Main
    Dim strSearched = <html>
                          <head>
                              <title>This is a test</title>
                          </head>
                          <body>
                              <h1>DA:TG01</h1>
                              <p>First paragraph</p>
                              <h2>This is a test 2</h2>
                              <!--More boring stuff omitted-->
                          </body>
                      </html>.ToString

    Dim ResultString As String
    Dim myMatchEvaluator As MatchEvaluator = New MatchEvaluator(AddressOf ComputeReplacement)

    ResultString = Regex.Replace(strSearched,
                                 "<(?'TagName'h[1-5])>(?'TagValue'.*?)</\k<TagName>>",
                                 myMatchEvaluator,
                                 RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)


End Sub

Public Function ComputeReplacement(ByVal m As Match) As String
    ' Need to replace the Group('value') here

    Return strRetValue
End Function
```

In the Function ComputeReplacement, I need to replace the Group("TagValue") with another value and return back the match string, eg:

If the match was `<h1>AAA</h1>` I would need it to return `<h1>BBB</h1>`
while if the match was `<h2>AAA</h2>` I would need it to return `<h2>BBB</h2>`

Comment: [you should consider a DOM parser instead of regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: If you fixed this yourself could you add an answer explaining what you did?

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not fix it.
For the above example I am just re building the string manually. But I have more complex regex, in which case I have to make a separate `ComputreReplacement` function for each.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use something to convert to XML and use xpath,
you could use one of these solutions:

HtmlAgilityPack : http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com
SGMLReader : http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader